# How can I set -profile main in ffmpeg when steaming

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ffserver

Im trying to stream my desktop to ffsever server with ffmpeg and I discovered that browser does not wont to play H.264 (High profile) videos only main and lowers so I added

```
-c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0
```

to my CLI bit Im getting an error

```
Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'high'
```

here is my CLI

```
ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -framerate 60 -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -i default -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -profile:v high http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

and here is whole log

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[x11grab @ 0x55b5676c39e0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[mpeg1video @ 0x55b567710920] [Eval @ 0x7ffe6c87d5d0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'high'
[mpeg1video @ 0x55b567710920] Unable to parse option value "high"
[mpeg1video @ 0x55b567710920] Error setting option profile to value high.
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x55b56771d3e0] Qavg: -nan
[alsa @ 0x55b5676ccc00] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Conversion failed!
```

**EDIT:**
So here is my CLI

```
./ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -framerate 60 -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -i default -c:a aac -c:v libx264 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

And here is mine `ffserver.conf`

```
<Stream h264>
Format webm
Feed feed1.ffm
VideoCodec libx264
VideoFrameRate 24
VideoBitRate 100
VideoSize 480x272
#AVPresetVideo default
#AVPresetVideo baseline
AVOptionVideo profile main
PixelFormat yuv420p
#
AudioCodec aac
AudioBitRate 32
AudioChannels 2
AudioSampleRate 22050
AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
</Stream>
```

and setup like that does not show up video in browser

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding with mpeg1video, not libx264.

mpeg1video does not support `-profile:v high`.

I'm guessing `-c:v`, and all other output options, are ignored for FFM output and the encoder is determined by `VideoCodec` in `ffserver.conf`. (But I was lazy and didn't confirm and have no experience with `ffserver`.) If you have no `VideoCodec` set then a default encoder will likely be selected determined by the chosen `Format` in `ffserver.conf`.

To your `<Stream>` section add:

```
VideoCodec libx264
AudioCodec aac
AVOptionVideo profile main
PixelFormat yuv420p
```

Comment: You said "that I encoding with mpeg1video" so I how I can encode with libx264 ? Also I  edited my question and it does not work when I add those parameters to `ffserver,conf`

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic Original question has been solved. Now you are encountering a new, different issue. Should be a new, separate question.

Comment: Hey @llogan here is mine new question https://superuser.com/questions/1607140/error-setting-profile-main-in-ffserver tnx