# PixelFormat ignored in ffserver.conf

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ffserver

Im trying to stream my desktop screen to browser on my tv with ffmpeg so here is my CLI

```
./ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -framerate 60 -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -i default -c:a aac -c:v libx264 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

And here is mine `ffserver.conf`

```
<Stream h264>
Format webm
Feed feed1.ffm
VideoCodec libx264
VideoFrameRate 24
VideoBitRate 100
VideoSize 480x272
#AVPresetVideo default
#AVPresetVideo baseline
AVOptionVideo profile main
PixelFormat yuv420p
#
AudioCodec aac
AudioBitRate 32
AudioChannels 2
AudioSampleRate 22050
AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
</Stream>
```

and here is an error that Im getting

```
[x11grab @ 0x55ff0e354a00] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[msmpeg4 @ 0x55ff0e3ab840] rc buffer underflow
[msmpeg4 @ 0x55ff0e3ab840] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:4:4
[libx264 @ 0x55ff0e3b4ca0] Error setting profile baseline.
[libx264 @ 0x55ff0e3b4ca0] Possible profiles: baseline main high high10 high422 high444
Error initializing output stream 0:5 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:5 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x55ff0e3b36c0] Qavg: -nan
[alsa @ 0x55ff0e35dc40] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Conversion failed!
```

so what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: It appears you are now able to set the H.264 profile. However, your selected H.264 profile is not compatible with 4:4:4 chroma subsampling. `PixelFormat yuv420p` is supposed to fix that but in your case it appears to be ignored. I don't know why. Unrelated, but H.264 + AAC don't go in WebM.

Comment: @llogan I tried to set format to rtp but vlc cant open it https://imgur.com/a/fjFuFvu

Comment: @llogan how can I set -level:v to be 4.0 and container Quicktime ?